# Making only the grid lines of a grid object visible in the the Render Viewport

Tags: rendering, objects

I would like to use a grid object as an orientation tool, for properly arranging objects against my HDRI background scene. This requires that the grid lines (and **only** the grid lines) of the grid object are visible in the Render Viewport.

However, in the Render Viewport, the grid object shows up as a solid rectangular plane, without grid lines. The only viewport in which the grid lines are visible is the Wireframe Viewport.

How can the grid lines (and only the grid lines, so you keep seeing the HDRI background) be made to show in the Render Viewport?

Comment: Delete > Only Faces leaves you with just the vertices and edges of your grid. Does that show up enough against your background in Material Preview mode?

Comment: Of course it does. Sorry, had a moment of overload and could no longer see the wood through the trees.